# STM32429ZI Dısc1 Gyro wrong data problem

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, gyro

I'm tring to write own L3GD20 library. I can read chip ID (but L3G sent to me ffd4 and its partially true). But I cannot read any axis of gyro. Partially gyro always sent to me FF or 00. I'm doing something wrong but I dont know what's wrong. How can I fix this.

L3GD20 header file is following:

```
    #define READ_DATA_MASK_FOR_L3GD20   0x8000
#define WRITE_DATA_MASK_FOR_L3GD20  ~(READ_DATA_MASK_FOR_L3GD20) & 0xFF00


typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef enum
{
WHO_AM_I        =   (byte)0x0F, 
CTRL_REG1       =   (byte)0x20,   
CTRL_REG2       =   (byte)0x21,   
CTRL_REG3       =   (byte)0x22,   
CTRL_REG4       =   (byte)0x23,   
CTRL_REG5       =   (byte)0x24,   
REFERENCE       =   (byte)0x25,   
OUT_TEMP        =   (byte)0x26,   
STATUS_REG      =   (byte)0x27,   
OUT_X_L             =   (byte)0x28,   
OUT_X_H             =   (byte)0x29,   
OUT_Y_L             =   (byte)0x2A,   
OUT_Y_H             =   (byte)0x2B,   
OUT_Z_L             =   (byte)0x2C,   
OUT_Z_H             =   (byte)0x2D,   
FIFO_CTRL_REG = (byte)0x2E,   
FIFO_SRC_REG  = (byte)0x2F,   
INT1_CFG        =   (byte)0x30,   
INT1_SRC            =   (byte)0x31,   
INT1_TSH_XH     = (byte)0x32,   
INT1_TSH_XL     =   (byte)0x33,   
INT1_TSH_YH     =   (byte)0x34,   
INT1_TSH_YL     =   (byte)0x35,   
INT1_TSH_ZH     =   (byte)0x36,   
INT1_TSH_ZL     =   (byte)0x37,   
INT1_DURATION = (byte)0x38      
} L3GD20_Reg_Map;
typedef enum
{
WHO_AM_I_Default_value          =   (byte)0xd4, //11010100
CTRL_REG1_Default_value         =   (byte)0x07, //00000111
CTRL_REG2_Default_value         =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
CTRL_REG3_Default_value         =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
CTRL_REG4_Default_value         =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
CTRL_REG5_Default_value         =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
REFERENCE_Default_value         =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
FIFO_CTRL_REG_Default_value =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_CFG_Default_value          =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_TSH_XH_Default_value   =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_TSH_XL_Default_value   =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_TSH_YH_Default_value   =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_TSH_YL_Default_value   =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_TSH_ZH_Default_value   =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_TSH_ZL_Default_value   =   (byte)0x00, //00000000
INT1_DURATION_Default_value =   (byte)0x00  //00000000  
} L3GD20_Reg_Map_Default_value;  
// take or
typedef enum
{
    CTRL_REG1_ODR_95Hz_VALUE                = (byte)0x00,
    CTRL_REG1_ODR_190Hz_VALUE             = (byte)0x40,
    CTRL_REG1_ODR_380Hz_VALUE           = (byte)0x80,
    CTRL_REG1_ODR_760Hz_VALUE           = (byte)0xC0,

    CTRL_REG1_BW_Select1_VALUE      = (byte)0x00,
    CTRL_REG1_BW_Select2_VALUE          = (byte)0x10,
    CTRL_REG1_BW_Select3_VALUE      = (byte)0x20,
    CTRL_REG1_BW_Select4_VALUE      = (byte)0x30,

    CTRL_REG1_PD_POWER_DOWN_VALUE     = (byte)0x00, 
    CTRL_REG1_PD_SLEEP_VALUE            = (byte)0x08,

    CTRL_REG1_ZEN_VALUE                         =   (byte)0x04,
    CTRL_REG1_YEN_VALUE                         =   (byte)0x02,
    CTRL_REG1_XEN_VALUE                         =   (byte)0x01,
    CTRL_REG1_XYZEN_VALUE                       =   (byte)0x07, 

} L3GD20_CTRL_REG1_VALUE;    
// take and

typedef enum
{
    CTRL_REG1_ODR_MASK              = (byte)0x3F,
    CTRL_REG1_BW_MASK               = (byte)0xCF,
    CTRL_REG1_PD_MASK                   = (byte)0xF7,
    CTRL_REG1_PD_Sleep_MASK     = (byte)0xF0,
    CTRL_REG1_ZEN_MASK              = (byte)0xFB,
    CTRL_REG1_YEN_MASK              = (byte)0xFD,
    CTRL_REG1_XEN_MASK              = (byte)0xFE,
    CTRL_REG1_XYZEN_MASK            = (byte)0xF8,   

} L3GD20_CTRL_REG1_MASK;    

typedef enum
{
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPM_RESET_READING_VALUE            = (byte)0x00,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPM_REF_SIG_FOR_FILT_VALUE     = (byte)0x10,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPM_NORMAL_MODE_VALUE              = (byte)0x20,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPM_AUTORES_INT_EVENT_VALUE    = (byte)0x30,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select1_VALUE                     = (byte)0x00,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select2_VALUE                     = (byte)0x01,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select3_VALUE                     = (byte)0x02,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select4_VALUE                     = (byte)0x03,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select5_VALUE                     = (byte)0x04,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select6_VALUE                     = (byte)0x05,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select7_VALUE                     = (byte)0x06,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select8_VALUE                     = (byte)0x07,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select9_VALUE                     = (byte)0x08,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_Select10_VALUE                    = (byte)0x09,
} L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_VALUE;    
// take and

typedef enum
{
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPM_MASK   = (byte)0xCF,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_HPCF_MASK  = (byte)0x0F

} L3GD20_CTRL_REG2_MASK;

typedef enum
{
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I1_Int1_VALUE      =   (byte)0x80,     //Interrupt enable on INT1 pin. Default value 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I1_Boot_VALUE      =   (byte)0x40,     //Boot status available on INT1. Default value 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_H_Lactive_VALUE    =   (byte)0x20,     //Interrupt active configuration on INT1. Default value 0. (0: high; 1:low)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_PP_OD_VALUE            =   (byte)0x1F,     //Push-pull / Open drain. Default value: 0. (0: push- pull; 1: open drain)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_DRDY_VALUE      =   (byte)0x08,     // Date-ready on DRDY/INT2. Default value 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_WTM_VALUE       =   (byte)0x04,     //FIFO watermark interrupt on DRDY/INT2. Default value: 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_ORun_VALUE      =   (byte)0x02,     //FIFO overrun interrupt on DRDY/INT2 Default value: 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_Empty_VALUE     =   (byte)0x01          //FIFO empty interrupt on DRDY/INT2. Default value: 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
} L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_VALUE;    
// take and

typedef enum
{
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I1_Int1_MASK       =   (byte)0x7F,     //Interrupt enable on INT1 pin. Default value 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I1_Boot_MASK   =   (byte)0xBF,     //Boot status available on INT1. Default value 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_H_Lactive_MASK =   (byte)0xDF,     //Interrupt active configuration on INT1. Default value 0. (0: high; 1:low)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_PP_OD_MASK         =   (byte)0xEF,     //Push-pull / Open drain. Default value: 0. (0: push- pull; 1: open drain)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_DRDY_MASK       =   (byte)0xF7,     // Date-ready on DRDY/INT2. Default value 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_WTM_MASK        =   (byte)0xFB,     //FIFO watermark interrupt on DRDY/INT2. Default value: 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_ORun_MASK   =   (byte)0xFD,     //FIFO overrun interrupt on DRDY/INT2 Default value: 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)
        L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_I2_Empty_MASK  =   (byte)0xFE          //FIFO empty interrupt on DRDY/INT2. Default value: 0. (0: disable; 1: enable)

} L3GD20_CTRL_REG3_MASK;

typedef enum
{
    CTRL_REG4_BDU_CONTINUOS                 =   (byte)0x00,
    CTRL_REG4_BDU_NOT_CONTINUOS         = (byte)0x80,
    CTRL_REG4_LBE_LSB                           =   (byte)0x00,
    CTRL_REG4_LBE_MSB                               = (byte)0x40,
    CTRL_REG4_FS_250                                = (byte)0x00,
    CTRL_REG4_FS_500                                =   (byte)0x10,
    CTRL_REG4_FS_2000                               = (byte)0x20,
} L3GD20_CTRL_REG4_VALUE;    
// take and

typedef enum
{
    CTRL_REG4_BDU_MASK  = 0x7F,
    CTRL_REG4_BLE_MASK  =   0xBF,
    CTRL_REG4_FS_MASK   =   0xCF,

} L3GD20_CTRL_REG4_MASK;    

typedef enum
{

    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_BOOT_Normal_Mode_VALUE         =0x00,                                  //Reboot memory content. Default value: 0(0: normal mode; 1: reboot memory content)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_BOOT_RMC_Mode_VALUE                =0x80,
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_FIFO_EN_VALUE                          =0x40,                                  //FIFO enable. Default value: 0(0: FIFO disable; 1: FIFO Enable)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_HPen_VALUE                                 =0x00,                                  // High-pass filter enable. Default value: 0(0: HPF disabled; 1: HPF enabled See Figure 20)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_INT1_Sel1INT1_Sel0_VALUE       =0x00,                                  //INT1 selection configuration. Default value: 0(See Figure 20)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_Out_Sel1Out_Sel1_VALUE         =0x00                                       //Out selection configuration. Default value: 0(See Figure 20)
} L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_VALUE;    
// take and

typedef enum
{
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_BOOT__MASK                                 =0x7F,                                  //Reboot memory content. Default value: 0(0: normal mode; 1: reboot memory content)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_FIFO_EN_MASK                           =0xBF,                                  //FIFO enable. Default value: 0(0: FIFO disable; 1: FIFO Enable)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_HPen__MASK                                 =0xDF,                                  // High-pass filter enable. Default value: 0(0: HPF disabled; 1: HPF enabled See Figure 20)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_INT1_Sel1INT1_Sel0_MASK        =0xF3,                                  //INT1 selection configuration. Default value: 0(See Figure 20)
    L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_Out_Sel1Out_Sel1_MASK          =0xFC                                       //Out selection configuration. Default value: 0(See Figure 20)

} L3GD20_CTRL_REG5_MASK;    


typedef enum
{
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_FM_ByPassM_VALUE               =0x00   ,                                               // FIFO mode selection. Default value: 00 (see Table 41)
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_FM_FIFOM_VALUE                 =0x20   ,
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_FM_StreamM_VALUE               =0x40   ,
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_FM_StoFM_VALUE                 =0x60   ,
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_FM_BtoSM_VALUE                 =0x80
} L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_VALUE;    
// take and

typedef enum
{
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_FM_MASK    =0x1F,                                          // FIFO mode selection. Default value: 00 (see Table 41)
    L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_WTM_MASK =0xE0                                         // FIFO threshold. Watermark level setting

} L3GD20_FIFO_CTRL_REG_MASK;    


typedef struct
{
    volatile uint16_t AxisX;
    volatile uint16_t AxisY;
    volatile uint16_t AxisZ;
}Axis;

bool InitL3GD20(SPISelect SPS,GPIOSelect GS,uint32_t Pin);
bool CheckL3GD20(void);
void SetupCsPinForL3D20(GPIOSelect GS,uint32_t Pin);
void CsOnOfL3D20(void);
void CsOffOfL3D20(void);
void WriteL3GD20Register(L3GD20_Reg_Map RM,volatile byte Data);
uint16_t ReadL3GD20Register(L3GD20_Reg_Map RM);
uint16_t GetXValueFromL3GD20(void);
uint16_t GetYValueFromL3GD20(void);
uint16_t GetZValueFromL3GD20(void);
Axis GetXYZValueFromL3GD20(void);
uint16_t GetTempatureValueFromL3GD20(void);
void SetDefaultValueToL3GD20(void);

void SetupCtrlReg1(void);
```

L3d20 c file is following:

```
#include "L3GD20.h"

GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx;
SPI_TypeDef* SPIx;
uint16_t GPIO_Pin;

bool InitL3GD20(SPISelect SPS,GPIOSelect GS,uint32_t Pin)
{
        InitSPI(SPS,
                        SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex,
                        SPI_Mode_Master,
                        SPI_DataSize_16b,
                        SPI_CPOL_High,
                        SPI_CPHA_2Edge,
                        SPI_NSS_Soft,
                        SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_64,
                        SPI_FirstBit_MSB,
                        7);
    switch(SPS)
    {
        case sSPI1:     SPIx = SPI1;            break;
        case sSPI2:     SPIx = SPI2;            break;
        case sSPI3:     SPIx = SPI3;            break;
        case sSPI4:     SPIx = SPI4;            break;
        case sSPI5:     SPIx = SPI5;            break;
        case sSPI6:     SPIx = SPI6;            break;

    }
    CsOffOfL3D20();
    SetupCsPinForL3D20(GS,Pin);
    SetDefaultValueToL3GD20();
  SetupCtrlReg1();
    return CheckL3GD20();

}

bool CheckL3GD20(void)
{

        if(ReadL3GD20Register(WHO_AM_I) == WHO_AM_I_Default_value ) 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;

}

void SetupCsPinForL3D20(GPIOSelect                  GS,
                                                uint32_t                        Pin)
{
            InitGPIO(   GS,
                                GPIO_Mode_OUT,
                                GPIO_OType_PP,
                                GPIO_Speed_2MHz,
                                GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL,
                                Pin);
        switch(GS){ 
        case sGPIOA:        GPIOx = GPIOA;          break;
        case sGPIOB:        GPIOx = GPIOB;          break;
        case sGPIOC:        GPIOx = GPIOC;          break;
        case sGPIOD:        GPIOx = GPIOD;          break;
        case sGPIOE:        GPIOx = GPIOE;          break;
        case sGPIOF:        GPIOx = GPIOF;          break;
        case sGPIOG:        GPIOx = GPIOG;          break;
        case sGPIOH:        GPIOx = GPIOH;          break;
        case sGPIOI:        GPIOx = GPIOI;          break;
        case sGPIOJ:        GPIOx = GPIOJ;          break;
        case sGPIOK:        GPIOx = GPIOK;          break;}
        GPIO_Pin = Pin;
}

void CsOnOfL3D20(void)
{
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOx,GPIO_Pin);//SPI CS on
}
void CsOffOfL3D20(void)
{
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOx,GPIO_Pin);//SPI CS off
}

uint16_t ReadL3GD20Register(L3GD20_Reg_Map RM)
{
    uint16_t temp2;
    uint16_t temp1 =  0;
    temp1 =temp1 | (uint16_t)READ_DATA_MASK_FOR_L3GD20; // 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 1000 0000 0000 0000 = 1000 0000 0000 0000
    temp1 |= (RM<<8); // 1000 0000 0000 0000 | 00xx xxxx 0000 0000 = 10xx xxxx 0000 0000
    CsOnOfL3D20();
    WriteSPI(SPIx,temp1);
    temp2 = ReadSPI(SPIx) & 0x00ff;
    CsOffOfL3D20();
    return temp2  ;
}

void WriteL3GD20Register(L3GD20_Reg_Map RM,volatile byte Data)
{
    uint16_t temp1 =  0;
    temp1 =temp1 & (uint16_t)WRITE_DATA_MASK_FOR_L3GD20;//0b 0000 0000 0000 00000 & 0b 0011 1111 0000 0000 = 0000 0000 0000 0000
    temp1 |= (RM<<8);// 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 00xx xxxx 0000 0000 = 00xx xxxx 0000 0000
    temp1 |= Data;// 00xx xxxx 0000 00000 | 0000 0000 yyyy yyyy = 00xx xxxx yyyy yyyy
    CsOnOfL3D20();
    WriteSPI(SPIx,temp1);
    CsOffOfL3D20();
}

void SetDefaultValueToL3GD20()
{
        WriteL3GD20Register(CTRL_REG1       ,       CTRL_REG1_Default_value         );  //00000111
        WriteL3GD20Register(CTRL_REG2       ,       CTRL_REG2_Default_value         );  //00000000
        WriteL3GD20Register(CTRL_REG3       ,       CTRL_REG3_Default_value         );  //00000000
        WriteL3GD20Register(CTRL_REG4       ,       CTRL_REG4_Default_value         );  //00000000  
        WriteL3GD20Register(CTRL_REG5       ,       CTRL_REG5_Default_value         );  //00000000  
        WriteL3GD20Register(REFERENCE     ,     REFERENCE_Default_value         );  //00000000  
        WriteL3GD20Register(FIFO_CTRL_REG ,     FIFO_CTRL_REG_Default_value );  //00000000   
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_CFG        ,       INT1_CFG_Default_value          );  //00000000 
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_TSH_XH     ,       INT1_TSH_XH_Default_value   );  //00000000
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_TSH_XL     ,   INT1_TSH_XL_Default_value   );  //00000000
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_TSH_YH     ,   INT1_TSH_YH_Default_value   );  //00000000
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_TSH_YL     ,   INT1_TSH_YL_Default_value   );  //00000000
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_TSH_ZH     ,       INT1_TSH_ZH_Default_value   );  //00000000   
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_TSH_ZL     ,       INT1_TSH_ZL_Default_value   );  //00000000   
        WriteL3GD20Register(INT1_DURATION ,     INT1_DURATION_Default_value );  //00000000      
}
uint16_t GetXValueFromL3GD20()
{
    uint16_t temp = ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_X_H);
    temp = temp<<8;
    temp |= ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_X_L);
    return temp;    
}

uint16_t GetYValueFromL3GD20()
{
    uint16_t temp = ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_Y_H);
    temp = temp<<8;
    temp |= ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_Y_L);
    return temp;    
}
uint16_t GetZValueFromL3GD20()
{
    uint16_t temp = ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_Z_H);
    temp = temp<<8;
    temp |= ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_Z_L);
    return temp;    
}
uint16_t GetTempatureValueFromL3GD20()
{
    uint16_t temp = ReadL3GD20Register(OUT_TEMP);
    return temp;    
}

void SetupCtrlReg1(void)
{
    byte temp = 0x00;

    // Enable Sensor

    temp &=     CTRL_REG1_PD_Sleep_MASK ;
    temp |=     CTRL_REG1_PD_SLEEP_VALUE    ;
    temp |=   CTRL_REG1_XYZEN_VALUE;
    temp &=     CTRL_REG1_ODR_MASK;
    temp |=   CTRL_REG1_ODR_95Hz_VALUE;
    temp &=     CTRL_REG1_BW_MASK;
    temp |=   CTRL_REG1_BW_Select1_VALUE;

    WriteL3GD20Register(CTRL_REG1,temp);

}


Axis GetXYZValueFromL3GD20(void)
{
    Axis ax;

    ax.AxisX = GetXValueFromL3GD20();
    ax.AxisY = GetYValueFromL3GD20();
    ax.AxisZ = GetZValueFromL3GD20();


    return ax;

}
```

and last main is :

```
InitL3GD20(sSPI5,sGPIOC,GPIO_Pin_1);
for(;;){
        //SetupCtrlReg1();
        ax = GetXYZValueFromL3GD20();
        SendStringUsart( USART2,  "AxisX:\n\r\t");
        SendStringUsart( USART2,  "\n\r");
        SendFloatUsart( USART2, (ax.AxisX*8.75)/1000);
        SendStringUsart( USART2,  "\n\r");
        _delay_ms(50);
        if(CheckL3GD20())
        {
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOG,GPIO_Pin_13);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOG,GPIO_Pin_14);
        }
        else
        {
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOG,GPIO_Pin_14);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOG,GPIO_Pin_13);

        }
```

spı functions:

```
uint16_t ReadSPI(SPI_TypeDef* SPIx)
{
    while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPIx,SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE));
    return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPIx);

}
void WriteSPI(SPI_TypeDef* SPIx, uint16_t Data)
{
        while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPIx,SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE));
        SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx,Data);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to verify that the SPI commands sent by the MCU are correct (using an oscilloscope or function generator?  If you wrote your SPI driver yourself, note that the STM32 parts require special care to write a single byte at a time due to the way the FIFO is handled. Does your SPI mode match that required by the gyro?

Comment: @ajb Yes, I'm verify. But My SPI driver(for L3G) is send 16 bit. I'm tring to send 8 bit. thank you

Comment: @jsotola The link is not appear

Comment: here is a link to another library ..... maybe you can use it to test the hardware .....  note: i have no way to test the library, so i do not know if it actually works .... https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/08/library-28-l3gd20-3-axis-gyroscope/

Comment: @RageLog, do you mean you are trying to send 8 bits but the SPI sends 16 bits instead?  If so this is a "feature" of the STM32 SPI module.  The data register requires special handling in 8-bit mode.  Can you share the source code for your `ReadSPI` and `WriteSPI` functions?

Comment: @ajb No I'm send 16 bit. 429 support 8 bit or 16 bit sent data I'm select 16 in initl3g function. I'm share read write spı function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your comments, then issue is with you sending 16bit words instead of 8 bit. You are sending 16 bits because it's defined in you SPI init struct (SPI_DataSize_16b).

Edit after comment:

Actually, now that I looked through, it seems that you are actually receiving dummy data of only the first word. See Section 5.2 of L3GD20 datasheet for SPI details.You do have to send 2x 8bit words to the sensor. First word contains R/W direction bit and the register address. To this sensor most likely replies with dummy 0xFF or 0x00. Starting from the next 8+ clocks sensor will dump the data from the address. This might explain why you sometimes get some data - it is previous data from the internal sensor FIFO buffer from the last request register address. So, to reiterate - try receiving 2 or more bytes instead of one and read all the response except the first byte

Comment: No it not the problem :( I'm change the bit size but problem not fix. My problem is always I receive exactly the same data all cycle of read. When I first changed I received different data but only once. Im look the this exemple https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/08/library-28-l3gd20-3-axis-gyroscope/
But result same

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: thank you for answer. Its some time work some time not work. I m tring

Comment: Try receiving 3 8bit words, instead of 2 (each measurement is 16 bits, transferred from separate registers + 8 bit dummy)